# Calling an element from an array and assigning it to a variable?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, nsmutablearray, element

could someone please tell me how to call an element from an array and assigning it to a variable?

In my viewdidload I create a random array of numbers.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    int n = 40;
    NSMutableArray *numbers = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        [numbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    while ([numbers count] > 0) {
        int r = arc4random() % [numbers count];
        NSNumber *randomElement = [numbers objectAtIndex:r];
        [result addObject:randomElement];
        [numbers removeObjectAtIndex:r];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
    NSLog (@"The 4th integer is: %@", [result objectAtIndex:3]);
}
```

In another section I would like to call those values.
For example

```
-(void)nextpiece{
    countnumber=2;
    count=[result objectAtIndex:countnumber];
}
```

with countnumber and count being int. The problem is it doesn't recognize the result array. Error is "Use of undeclared identifier 'result'" 
Could someone provide a solution? Thank you very much

Comment: Can you explain the problem again? It's quite hard to understand `The problem is it doesn't recognize the result array`. What do you expect here?

Comment: I added more code and the error I'm getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is because `result` is a local variable inside `viewDidLoad` and you can only use it inside `viewDidLoad`. If you want a variable which can be used in both `viewDidLoad` and `nextpiece`. I suggest to make `result` as a property of your class.

For example.

```
@interface YourViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* result;

@end

@implementation YourViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  int n = 40;
  NSMutableArray *numbers = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    [numbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
  }
  _result = [NSMutableArray array];
  while ([numbers count] > 0) {
    int r = arc4random() % [numbers count];
    NSNumber *randomElement = [numbers objectAtIndex:r];
    [_result addObject:randomElement];
    [numbers removeObjectAtIndex:r];
  }
  NSLog(@"%@", _result);
  NSLog (@"The 4th integer is: %@", [_result objectAtIndex:3]);
}

-(void)nextpiece{
  int countnumber = 2;
  NSNumber *count = [_result objectAtIndex:countnumber];
}

@end
```

Comment: OK I understand. Thank you very much. Just curious how I would need to declare count to use it as a variable in other places? For example with an if statement. if(count==1){

Comment: I’m not sure what count is. But if you can get it from result, I think you don’t need to make it as a property. Whenever you need count to use, get it from result.

Comment: Thanks, I was about to use the [[result objectAtIndex:countnumber]integerValue] instead of count.